# Microphone on Arduino for Sound Detection

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, operational-amplifier, audio, microphone

I'm working on a design to have a microphone on Arduino board for sound detection (clapping sound etc). I see there are lot of circuits floating on internet but almost everyone has an output to ADC pin on Arduino. On my design, all the ADC pins are exhausted (using 6 PIR sensors), so i'm left with digital pins.

How can i use an analog microphone on digital pin, can it be done through peak detection circuit? Can anyone share a reference schematic?

Also, an audio amplifier is required or can i get this done through a rail to rail opamp with good slew rate?

Comment: Yes, a peak detection circuit will work. There are loads of schematic online, try one. And yes, a single R2R op-amp would be sufficient. It doesn't even need to have "good" slew rate, audio is _slow_.

Comment: @uint128_t: Thanks! What basically im looking is a 0 or 1 logic for no sound and sound logic. Do you have any reference schematic or design which can be useful for me...

Comment: Typing "arduino audio peak detector" into das Google might be a good place to start...

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, typing "Arduino peak detector" on google can give a few ways to go. I added "Sparkfun" to the search because they tend to have useful breakouts and decent documentation.

In [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12642) product, you will find the following schematic:

[image: Arduino mic peak detection]

Which pretty much gives what you want.

Please note the [licensing](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) mode.